# SQL Redshift how to shift cell values based on other column values and then sum up

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Data preparation:

```
CREATE TABLE test_work_day
(
  work_day  integer ,
  send_date DATE ,
  volume  integer,
  week_day varchar,
  hols varchar
);
insert into test_work_day values
(0, '2022-05-21', 0, 'Saturday',null),
(0, '2022-05-22', 0, 'Sunday',null),
(1, '2022-05-23', 0, 'Monday',null),
(1, '2022-05-24', 99, 'Tuesday',null),
(1, '2022-05-25', 111,'Wednesday',null),
(0, '2022-05-26', 154, 'Thursday', 'Public_holiday' ),
(1, '2022-05-27', 200, 'Friday',null),
(0, '2022-05-28', 0, 'Saturday',null),
(0, '2022-05-29', 0, 'Sunday',null),
(0, '2022-05-30', 0, 'Monday', 'Public_holiday'),
(1, '2022-05-31', 164, 'Tuesday',null),
(1, '2022-06-01', 123, 'Wednesday',null),
(1, '2022-06-02', 189, 'Thursday',null),
(1, '2022-06-03', 150, 'Friday',null),
(0, '2022-06-04', 0, 'Saturday',null),
(0, '2022-06-05', 0, 'Sunday',null),
(1, '2022-06-06', 100, 'Monday',null),
(1, '2022-06-07', 200, 'Tuesday',null);

select * from test_work_day;
```

Output:

[image]

When value = 0 in column 'work_day' the value ( and the following values ) from the column 'volume' should be shifted down to the point where the value in column 'work_day' = 1. If there are three 0 in a row the value should be shifted to the first row where work_day = 1. Volumes should be align only with work_day = 1

On the 8th calendar day from the first work_day = 0 (26/05/2022), there is a catch-up moment where the previous value and the current value are summed up.

Desired output:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: The data you inputted does not match the output you provided.

Comment: Apologies, updated now.

Answer (score 0):

If WITH expression is supported:

```
;WITH cteShiftIndex AS
(
    SELECT work_day,
       send_date,
       volume,
       CASE WHEN Volume = 0 THEN NULL 
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN Volume = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ORDER BY send_date ASC)
            END AS RowIndex,
       SUM(work_day) OVER (ORDER BY send_date) AS WorkIndex
    FROM test_work_day
)
SELECT 
    cte.work_day,
    cte.send_date,
    cte.Volume,
    CASE WHEN cte.work_day = 0 
         THEN 0 ELSE cte2.volume
         END AS VolumeAdjusted
FROM cteShiftIndex cte
    LEFT JOIN cteShiftIndex cte2 ON cte.WorkIndex = cte2.RowIndex
ORDER BY cte.send_date
```

**UPDATED (with SUM logic)**

```
;WITH cteShiftIndex AS
(
    SELECT work_day,
       send_date,
       volume,
       CASE WHEN Volume = 0 THEN NULL 
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN Volume = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ORDER BY send_date ASC)
            END AS RowIndex,
       SUM(work_day) OVER (ORDER BY send_date) AS WorkIndex
    FROM test_work_day
)
, cteGroupedShiftIndex AS
(
    SELECT *,
        SUM(volume) OVER (ORDER BY send_date) AS TotalVolume,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CEILING(WorkIndex / 7.0)) AS GroupIndex
    FROM cteShiftIndex
)
SELECT 
    cte.work_day,
    cte.send_date,
    cte.Volume,
    CASE WHEN cte.work_day = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN cte.WorkIndex % 7 = 0 THEN -- to do the SUM every 7th working day
                cte2.Volume +
                SUM(cte.Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY cte2.GroupIndex ORDER BY cte.send_date) - 
                SUM(CASE WHEN cte.work_day = 0 
                         THEN 0
                         ELSE cte2.volume END) OVER (PARTITION BY cte2.GroupIndex ORDER BY cte.send_date)
         ELSE cte2.volume
    END AS VolumeAdjusted
FROM cteGroupedShiftIndex cte
    LEFT JOIN cteGroupedShiftIndex cte2 ON (cte.WorkIndex + cte.GroupIndex - 1) = cte2.RowIndex
ORDER BY cte.send_date
```

Comment: Many thanks @babymilo your solution works fine. However, I would like to 'sum' Volume and VolumeAdjusted on the 7th working day so it = 339 (150 + 189)  and then start over again so VolumeAdjusted  on 06/06 is 100, on 07/06 is 200 and so on until the next future work_day = 0. Your suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Art I've updated the answer, is that what you're looking for? Will do the SUM up every 7th working day

Comment: Much appreciated @babymilo! I updated the input data with an unforeseen challenge. When the period starts with volume = 0 then volumes are adjusted the other way as the first row index's are null. Also, I added column 'hols' that identifies public holidays so the 7th working day counter should start when 'hols' = 'Public holiday'. If there is another 'Public holiday' within the 7th working day window it should be ignored. Weekends don't count as they always have 'value' = 0. Many thanks!

Comment: HI @babymilo would you be able to advise how to do it?

Comment: Sorry @Art, I don't really understand this statement "the 7th working day counter should start when 'hols' = 'Public holiday'. If there is another 'Public holiday' within the 7th working day window it should be ignored". Could you provide the expected data instead, and highlight where's exactly the counter shall begin?

Comment: Many thanks @babymilo ! I updated the desired output above. So, the calendar starts on 21/05, Saturday so volume = 0. Then we have a public holiday on 26/05 and the counter starts. The during the counter run another public holidays occurs on 30/05, Monday. Since this is a second public holiday that occurs within 7 working days from the first one we move this volume to next day. On 31/05 we have 210 ( 200 that has been pushed bu the counter plus 10 from the second public holiday). Then on 02/06 we have the counter catch up day and the counter reset. It starts again at next public holiday.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected results does not exactly align to your explanation, but this reads like a gaps-and-islands problem, where each island is a working day, possibly preceded by a number of non-working days.

We can identify islands with a window sum (the trick is to order the partition by descending date to match the logic you want), then use conditional expressions:

```
select work_day, send_date, volume, 
    case when work_day = 1 then sum(volume) over(partition by grp) else volume end as new_volume
from (
    select t.*, sum(work_day) over(order by send_date desc) as grp
    from test_work_day t
) t
order by send_date
```

| work_day | send_date | volume | new_volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-24 | 99 | 99 |
| 1 | 2022-05-25 | 111 | 111 |
| 0 | 2022-05-26 | 154 | 154 |
| 1 | 2022-05-27 | 200 | 354 |
| 0 | 2022-05-28 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-05-29 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-05-30 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-05-31 | 164 | 164 |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 | 123 | 123 |
| 0 | 2022-06-02 | 189 | 189 |
| 0 | 2022-06-03 | 150 | 150 |
| 1 | 2022-06-04 | 0 | 339 |
| 1 | 2022-06-05 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-06-06 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-06-07 | 200 | 200 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pZKZ-LxT)

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I amended the description. The important thing is that the summing occurs on the 8th working day from the first work_day = 0 date. As the following values are also pushed down so value 200 from 27/05/22 should be allocated to 31/05/22 and so on. Avoiding work_day = 0. On 03/06/22 we sum up 189 from the previous day and 150 from 03/06/22  so the total is 339. Hope this make sense. Cheers, A.